# javascript to synchronise the scrolling of two list boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

How can we synchronise the scrolling of two list boxes so that scrolling of one list box results in scrolling of the other list box.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I've successfully used the `onscroll` event to synchronise `div` and `iframe` elements, though I have a vague memory that (unfortunately) `select` elements don't support `onscroll` (or maybe it is only certain browsers that don't support it), so that may not help - can I leave it to you to do some more research on that? I'm assuming when you say "list boxes" you mean select elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have some guidelines:

- Use the `scroll` events on both listboxes `$(".listbox").bind("scroll", ...)`
- Inside it, get the scrolled coordinate with `scrollTop` css
- Use this value to change the other listbox's `scrollTop`

This way both will scroll together.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

ASSUMING you mean the form SELECT object

There are several questions that make me think not all browsers will do what you want.

Here is the simplest plain JS with inline event handler

```
<select id="sel1" name="sel1" onchange="this.form.sel2.selectedIndex=this.selectedIndex">
.
.
.
<select id="sel2" name="sel2" onchange="this.form.sel1.selectedIndex=this.selectedIndex">
.
.
.
```

jQuery (not tested)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sel1").change(function() {
    $("#sel2").attr("selectedIndex",$(this).attr("selectedIndex"));
  }
  $("#sel2").change(function() {
    $("#sel1").attr("selectedIndex",$(this).attr("selectedIndex"));
  }
}
```